# Pandas - Getting weird indexing and shape when reading multiple CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read and merge some CSVs but I am getting an index added, which is messing up the final CSV.
I have tried `index_col=None`, `index_col=False` and `index_col=0` (since my first column is epoch time) but nothing seems to be helping.

CSV1:

```
1704067200000,0.14720000,0.15300000,0
1704153600000,0.15200000,0.15600000,0
```

CSV2:

```
1704758400000,0.13780000,0.13790000,0
1704844800000,0.13240000,0.13970000,0
```

I want this:

```
1704067200000,0.14720000,0.15300000,0
1704153600000,0.15200000,0.15600000,0
1704758400000,0.13780000,0.13790000,0
1704844800000,0.13240000,0.13970000,0
```

But getting this instead:

```
,1704067200000,0.14720000,0.15300000,0,1704758400000,0.13780000,0.13790000
0,1704153600000.0,0.152,0.156,0,,,
1,,,,0,1704844800000.0,0.1324,0.1397
```

The code I am using is this btw:

```
for folder in data_folders:
    data_lists = [pd.read_csv(csvfile, index_col=None) for csvfile in folder.glob('*.csv')]
    pd.concat(data_lists, ignore_index=True).to_csv(folder_1d / f"{coin_folder.name}.csv")
    print(data_lists)
```

Printing dataframe gives:

```
[   1704067200000  0.14720000  0.15300000  0
0  1704153600000       0.152       0.156  0,    Unnamed: 0  1704067200000  0.14720000  0.15300000  0  1704758400000  \
0           0   1.704154e+12       0.152       0.156  0            NaN   
1           1            NaN         NaN         NaN  0   1.704845e+12   

   0.13780000  0.13790000  
0         NaN         NaN  
1      0.1324      0.1397  ,    1704758400000  0.13780000  0.13790000  0
0  1704844800000      0.1324      0.1397  0]
```

I even tried

```
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_1d, "*.csv"))
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
```

But no solution still:

```
   1704067200000  0.14720000  0.15300000  0  1704758400000  0.13780000  \
0   1.704154e+12       0.152       0.156  0            NaN         NaN   
1            NaN         NaN         NaN  0   1.704845e+12      0.1324   

   0.13790000  
0         NaN  
1      0.1397
```

Pls help/advise. Please be kind, I am new to pandas :)

Comment: You need to `concat` your list of dataframes

Comment: Add `header=None` as well. So, probably `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csvfile, index_col=False, header=None) for csvfile in folder.glob('*.csv')])`

Comment: @mozway I did use `concat` twice in above example codes, see above, but still no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have no header, so you should read the csv without one using `header=None` in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Also export with `index=None, header=None` in [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
for folder in data_folders:
    data_lists = [pd.read_csv(csvfile, index_col=None, header=None)
                  for csvfile in folder.glob('*.csv')]
    (pd.concat(data_lists, ignore_index=True)
       .to_csv(folder_1d / f"{coin_folder.name}.csv",
               index=None, header=None)
     )
    print(data_lists)
```

Output:

```
1704067200000,0.1472,0.153,0
1704153600000,0.152,0.156,0
1704758400000,0.1378,0.1379,0
1704844800000,0.1324,0.1397,0
```